# React Native Hook- How to get the json data into state hook

Tags: json, react-native, react-hooks

I am working with React Native. I get the filtered data I need from json in "result" but I want to display this data into a react state hook and it shows an empty [].
I want the user to write the city and the picker to show the possible countries with that city.

---

**Here is mi JSON**

````
```
data:[
{
    "id": 1704127,
    "name": "Madridejos",
    "state": "",
    "country": "PH",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 123.346199,
      "lat": 9.79116
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1704129,
    "name": "Madrid",
    "state": "",
    "country": "PH",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 125.964371,
      "lat": 9.26211
    }
  },
]
```
````

**Here is my code:**

````
  ```
        
          const [value, setValue] = useState('')
          const [country, setCountry] = useState('')
          const [state,setState]=useState()
          var result
        
         
        
         const handleChange=(event)=>{
            setValue(event.target.value)
            if (event.target.value && event.target.value.length > 0) {
              conuntries(event.target.value)
            } else {
              setState({})
            }
        
        }
    const conuntries=(city)=>{
        const finalCity=
        city.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + city.slice(1)
        result=
        data.filter(d => d.name===finalCity)
        console.log('result', result)
        setState(result)
        console.log(state)
     
     }
    
    <View className="form-group">
              <TextInput placeholder='City' onChange={handleChange}value={value}
    
                name='city' type='text' className="form-control" />
            </View>
            <View className="form-group">`enter code here`
            <Picker
            selectedValue={country}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setCountry(itemValue)}
          >
          
          {state&& state.map(a => (
            <Picker.Item  key={`search-a-${a.id}`}style={styles.picker}label={a.country} value={a.country} />))}
           
            
          </Picker>
             
            </View>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by the codes bellow:

```
const [country, setCountry] = useState('')

const handleChange=(event)=>{
   if (event.target.value && event.target.value.length > 1) {
       conuntries(event.target.value)
    }
}
const conuntries=(city)=>{
    const finalCity= city.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + city.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    let result = data.filter(d => d.name===finalCity)
    if(result.length !== 0){
        setCountry(result)
        console.log(country)
    }
 
 }
```

if you want to get only one country, give the scenario that there can be multiple city in the same name from different countries, then you can get the first one by using

```
let result = data.filter(d => d.name===finalCity)[0]
```

**or the last one**

```
let result = data.filter(d => d.name===finalCity)
result = result[result.length -1]
```

Or you can use other custom functionalities with the **Country** state